# PL SQL Package to take backup of all tables in a schema

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to understand how i can proceed with a PL SQL Package that i can use to take backup of all the tables in a specific database as i need to keep this mandatory backup. while taking the backup i need to prefix the table names with bak_XX...

Can someone suggest please on how i can start of as i am not very familiar with PL SQL in oracle.

Thank You

I have started off with below script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY backup_scr AS

  FUNCTION get_tablenames(db_name VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
      v_dbnames VARCHAR2(150);
  BEGIN
    SELECT OBJECT_NAME || ','
    INTO v_dbnames
    FROM SYS.ALL_OBJECTS
    WHERE UPPER(OBJECT_TYPE) = 'PACKAGE';

    RETURN v_dbnames;

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in PL/SQL to backup the database to somewhere else inside the database? Use `RMAN` (or `EXPDP` or `EXP`) and backup to an external source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of function, write a procedure inside the `PACKAGE BODY` like this. Get the list of tables from `ALL_TABLES` , loop through it and dynamically run `CREATE TABLE` for backup table creation.

**Package Specification.**

```
create or replace PACKAGE backup_scr AS
    PROCEDURE p_backup_scr  (
        p_ret_code OUT NUMBER
    ) ;

END backup_scr ;
```

/

**Body**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY backup_scr AS

    PROCEDURE p_backup_scr (
        p_ret_code OUT NUMBER
    )
        IS
    BEGIN
        FOR tabs IN (
            SELECT
                owner,
                table_name
            FROM
                all_tables
        ) LOOP
            BEGIN
                dbms_output.put_line('CREATING BACKUP OF '
                || tabs.owner
                || '.'
                || tabs.table_name);

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE BAK_'
                || tabs.table_name
                || ' AS SELECT * FROM '
                || tabs.owner
                || '.'
                || tabs.table_name;

                dbms_output.put_line('COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY');
                p_ret_code := 0;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
                    p_ret_code := 1;
            END;
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
            p_ret_code := 1;
    END p_backup_scr;

END backup_scr;
/
```

You can then call your script from `sqlplus/ sql developer` as

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
variable return_code NUMBER;
EXEC backup_scr.p_backup_scr(:return_code);
PRINT return_code;
```

Note: You can add a where condition for specific schema in the select for `all_tables`. And if you want it to be more generic, then pass the schema name as `procedure` argument.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik but when i try to execute i am getting the error that package body created with errors, do i need to include create package stmt? Apologies as i am very new to packages..

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY backup_scr AS procedure backup_scr_sql will suffice?

Comment: You need to create the package spec with the same name first.Have you not created it?

Comment: Thanks Kaushik for your help! Apologies i overlooked the code for creation of the package and now seems working fine however seems the UID that i am using Scott doesn't have enough privileges to carry out the backup need to fix that.
Thanks again and good day!

Comment: Ok. If you found what you wanted. Please do upvote the answer and mark it as best answer.